# filename matching pattern

Tags: files

I have a folder of 200 satellite files to process. 
There are three steps in the process and I want to use a shell script under ubuntu to process them. I am using a for loop.

My problem is the filenames. An example is A2013290123000.L1A_LAC.Ireland.hdf.

I can create variables ie.

```
DATE=A2013
DATE1=`date +%j` #gives me the number of days since jan 1st 2013 in example above this would be 290
.L1A_LAC.Ireland.hdf part of the name doesn't change.
```

My issue is with the middle part of the name, in example above:123000

There is no pattern to this part of the name. It is a time stamp but varies with each file.

I want to create a variable in the script such as

```
TIMESTAMP=$DATE$DATE1$DATE2
```

Where DATE2= the middle part of the file name.

Is it possible to specify this variable as a wild card something like:

```
DATE2=$*
```

I hope to have the value of the variable `TIMESTAMP= A2013209123000`

```
#!/bin/sh

#set -e

set -x #debug mode

<<comment
export OCSSWROOT=/home/seadas/seadas-7.0/ocssw
source $OCSSWROOT/OCSSW_bash.env
export PATH=$PATH:/home/seadas/seadas-7.0/bin
comment

DATE=A2013
DATE1=`date +%j`
DATE2=$*
TIMESTAMP=$DATE$DATE1$DATE2
LOCATION_NAME=Ireland

DATADIR=/home/MODIS
L2_DIR=/home/MODIS/L2
GEO_FILE_DIR=/home/MODIS/GEO
L1B_DIR=/home/MODIS/L1B
SCRIPTDIR=/home/seadas/seadas-7.0/ocssw/run/scripts
FILTERDIR=/home/seadas/seadas-7.0/ocssw/run/data/common
FUNCTION=/home/seadas/seadas-7.0/ocssw/run/bin/linux_64

HDFFILE=$TIMESTAMP.L1A_LAC.$LOCATIONNAME.hdf
GEOFILE=$LOCATION_NAME-$TIMESTAMP.GEO
LACFILE=$TIMESTAMP.L1B_LAC
HKMFILE=$TIMESTAMP.L1B_HKM
QKMFILE=$TIMESTAMP.L1B_QKM
L2FILE=$TIMESTAMP.L2.hdf


for i in `ls -r $DATADIR`

do
    echo "Start a Process for file $i";

'Generating geolocation file' $SCRIPTDIR/modis_GEO.py -d $DATADIR/$HDFFILE -o $GEO_FILE_DIR/$TIMESTAMP.GEO --threshold=95;

'Generating L1B file' $SCRIPTDIR/modis_L1B.py $DATADIR/$HDFFILE $GEO_FILE_DIR/$TIMESTAMP.GEO -o $L1B_DIR/$LACFILE -k $L1B_DIR/$HKMFILE -q $L1B_DIR/$QKMFILE;

'Generating L2 product'$FUNCTION/l2gen ifile=$L1B_DIR/$LACFILE geofile=$GEO_FILE/$TIMESTAMP.GEO par=$FILTERDIR/msl12_defaults.par ofile=$L2_DIR/$L2FILE resolution=-1 l2prod="default,sst,qual_sst,qual_sst4,sstref,sst4" filter_opt=0 proc_ocean=1 gas_opt=15;

echo "it $i is finished..." 

    echo "\n"
done
```

Comment: I could answer if I could understand the question. What exactly are you trying to do? You have a filename A2013290123000.L1A_LAC.Ireland.hdf made up of an A a date (what date is 2012290?) 123000 and .LaA_LAC and you want to tokenise it, is this correct.

Comment: sounds like a job for a regex, but you will have to tell me what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work as you expect.

- In general, you should not loop over results of `ls` because it fails if you have special characters in the filenames (like whitespaces which is probably not the case for your problem);
- loop over the existing HDF-files and extract the TIMESTAMP from the filenames:

  ```
  # assuming you do not have whitespaces etc. in filenames
  for i in $DATADIR/$DATE$DATE1*.L1A_LAC.$LOCATIONNAME.hdf ; do
    if [ ! -f "$i" ] ; then  #check if pattern could be expanded
         break ; 
    fi
    HDFFILE="$i"
    TIMESTAMP=$(basename "$i" ".L1A_LAC.$LOCATIONNAME.hdf")
    GEOFILE=$LOCATION_NAME-$TIMESTAMP.GEO
    LACFILE=$TIMESTAMP.L1B_LAC
    HKMFILE=$TIMESTAMP.L1B_HKM
    QKMFILE=$TIMESTAMP.L1B_QKM
    L2FILE=$TIMESTAMP.L2.hdf

    # process $i
    # [...]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to remove everything after the first dot in your file name in order to obtain the time stamp. This [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) should help:

```
TIMESTAMP="${i%%.*}"
```